# How to select numeric string as a valid DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select, case

```
CUSTOMER(ID,NAME,ENTRY_DT)
         1,Dave,8312012
         2,Tom,11262013
         3,Iva,3312012
         .
         . 
         .
```

So the ENTRY_DT column has numeric string value in MDDYYYY or MMDDYYYY format.
I want to write a simple select query so that ENTRY_DT shows

```
8/31/2012
11/26/2013
3/31/2012
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (Int_Date INT)

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
(8312012),
(11262013),
(3312012)


SELECT  LEFT(RIGHT('00000000'+ CAST(Int_Date AS VARCHAR(10)), 8), 2) +'/' 
        +REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Int_Date), 5, 2)) + '/' + RIGHT(Int_Date, 4)
FROM @TABLE
```

### Result

```
08/31/2012
11/26/2013
03/31/2012
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select covert(date,right(('00000000' + entry_dt),8),101)
```

--- if it is SQL server 2008 or above

Replace date with date time if it is 2005 or below.

Comment: 101 is `mm/dd/yyyy` it assumes that there will be slashes in the date value.  this should fail. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, name, CONVERT(datetime, entry_dt, 101)
```

Comment: 104 is `dd.mm.yyyy`.  It assumes that you'll have periods in the date. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx, so this should fail.

Comment: Thanks @WickedFan but I am getting error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Just changed the 104 to 101 to express date fields with slashes - sorry, too quick for my shadow.

Comment: I think the point that there are NO slashes or dots in OP's data.  Only @M.Ali's answer, that parses the string, will create a correct datetime.

Comment: Sorry, got overly confused and thought you had slashes in your string field. Filling in zeros with a right() filler seems like the way to go and to run Convert() on the filled date.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT LEFT(RIGHT('00000000'+CAST(ENTRY_DT AS VARCHAR(10)),8),2)+'/'+REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ENTRY_DT), 5, 2))+'/'+REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ENTRY_DT), 1, 4)) FROM #CUSTOMER

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SUBSTRING(RIGHT('00000000'+ENTRY_DT,8),1,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(RIGHT('00000000'+ENTRY_DT,8),3,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(RIGHT('00000000'+ENTRY_DT,8),5,4) FROM #CUSTOMER